# Calculating Arithmetic Intensity

Tags: performance, machine-learning, gpu, artificial-intelligence, nvidia

Nvidia's GPU Performance Background User's Guide (https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/performance/dl-performance-gpu-background/index.html) lists the following arithmetic intensities for fp16 data opreations.

I'm trying to derive the AI math behind each of them.

| # | Operation | Arithmetic Intensity | Usually limited by |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Linear layer (4096 outputs, 1024 inputs, batch size 512) | 315 FLOPS/B | arithmetic |
| 2 | Linear layer (4096 outputs, 1024 inputs, batch size 1) | 1 FLOPS/B | memory |
| 3 | Max pooling with 3x3 window and unit stride | 2.25 FLOPS/B | memory |
| 4 | ReLU activation | 0.25 FLOPS/B | memory |
| 5 | Layer normalization | < 10 FLOPS/B | memory |

For #2 I get:

- Flops =  2 ops * 1024 inputs * 4096 weights each
- Memory =  2 bytes * (1024 input reads + 1024*4096 weight reads + 4096 write outputs)
- --> Flops/Memory ~= 1 Flops/B

What about the remaining operations?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the output activation requires 1024x2 = 2048 MACs.. (ignoring additions) i.e. 1024 weights need to be multiplied by 1024 input activation to produce one output activation. And there are 4096 output activations i.e. 2048*4096 = 8388608 MACs and batch size is 512 i.e. 4294967296 MACs

For memory accesses, we need to access 1024 input activations (read), 4096 output activations (write) for a batch size of 1, but we have a batch size of 512, each of these operands is assumed to be FP16. so, for input and output activations, we have

- input accesses = 1024 * 512 * 2 = 1048576
- output accesses = 4096 * 512 * 2 = 4194304
- weights = 1024 * 4096 * 2 = 8388608
  totaling to 13631488 and
  ratio of 4294967296 MACs / 13631488  bytes = 315